# How can I make Paypal button post async?

Tags: jquery, paypal

I want to send the form values to paypal using jquery Ajax.  I do not want Paypal to open a window showing the cart as I am just adding an item to the cart.  I will show the cart later with a View Cart button.

```
<form name="_xclick" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="HTML book">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="24.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0"      name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
</form>
```

Here is the jquery that I am trying to use:

```
var a=$('_xclick').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'https://www.paypal.com'
    }

});
```

This still opens a new paypal window showing ther cart.  Is there a way around this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using the add to cart button, it will open up the cart window each time that you add an item to it.  If you don't want this to happen, you may want to use the cart upload method instead of the add to cart buttons.  The cart upload method is what 3rd party carts use.  The cart or your site would keep track of what the buyer is adding to the cart, then at the time of checkout when the buyer is ready to pay you would redirect them over to PayPal and send all of the items in the cart over to PayPal.  You can find more on the cart upload command [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload).